# Execution by dependencies in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, dependencies, google-colaboratory, execution

I am using [execution_dependencies](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/execution_dependencies) to specify cell execution.

Here is a simple example:
I want to execute cell C first that depends on outputs from B and B depends on A

```
#C =>B   
y = y.subs({a:1,b:2})

#B =>A   
from sympy.abs import a,b
y= a+b
#A
from sympy import *
```

I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I have encount the similar problem.
Make sure you use the **tag toolbar** to insert tag, **NOT** insert tag in the cell block.

To see Tags Toolbar on your cells: `View - Cell Toolbar - Tags`
Use the **“Add tag”** button in Tag Toolbar, add following tags respectively in three cells as you want.

```
#C =>B   
#B =>A   
#A
```

Then, (in my computer) execute cell #C will execute cell #B and cell #A automatically.
This is a [demo ipynb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18_04w6L77c_v6n28TKHby-BH9gHzQFzJ/view?usp=sharing) of mine.

Comment: Can you add an explanation behind your answer.

Comment: the point of my answer is that  the  [execution_dependencies](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/execution_dependencies) manual may be a little confusing for person don't familar with tag of Jupyter notebook. So use **tag toolbar** to add tag instead of inserting tag in cell block.

Answer (score 0):

##### Through the Jupyter ui open the `Cell Tags` under the `COMMON TOOLS`

- For Jupyter Notebook: navigate through `View -> Right Sidebar -> Show Notebook Tools`
- For Jupyter Lab: go to the [Property Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgx4o.png) ⚙ (top right corner)

add tag `#A` for the first cell, for instance:

```py
import numpy as np
data = [(0 , 28), (1 , 22), (2 , 25), (3 , 45)]
```

add tag `=>#A` for the second cell, for instance:

```py
x, y = zip(*data)
```

##### Additional notes:

- these tags are saved in the .ipynb files and will still work if you switch from Jupyter Notebook to Jupyter Lab and vice versa
- you may need to run the first cell at least one time in order to then run the second cell independently